# In the numpy std calculation , np.std(y_test == y_test_predict), what is the meaning of comparing the test split and predicted result

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

Pl look at the K Neight classification ML algorithm using Python

```
 for i in range (0,Ks):
     neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = i+1).fit(x_train,y_train)
     y_test_predict = neigh.predict(x_test)
     mean_acc[i] = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_test_predict)
     std_acc[i] = np.std(y_test == y_test_predict)/np.sqrt(y_test_predict.shape[0])
```

I have 1 questions
(1)what is the meaning of the this statement "np.std(y_test == y_test_predict)". what will the output of the the operation y_test == y_test_predict and why that is being passed as an argument to the std() lib

also what is the logic behind the standard deviation formula

```
 std_acc[i] = np.std(y_test == y_test_predict)/np.sqrt(y_test_predict.shape[0])
```

(2) why std dev accuracy is computed as below:

```
 np.std(y_test == y_test_predict)/np.sqrt(y_test_predict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me break this up into two parts.

1. A comparison of two numpy arrays returns a boolean array. Assume that `y_test = np.array([0, 0, 1])` and `y_test_pred = np.array([0, 1, 1])`. Then, `y_test == y_test_pred` returns `array([True, False, True])`. Basically, an element-wise comparison of the two arrays are made according to index. If you understand this, now perhaps you can see the meaning behind `np.std(y_test == y_test_predict)`: it simply calculates the standard deviation of the boolean array returned by the comparison.
2. The formula `np.std(y_test == y_test_predict)/np.sqrt(y_test_predict.shape[0])` is basically taking the boolean array to compute its standard deviation, then dividing that standard deviation by the length of that array.

If anything is unclear, I'd be happy to provide further elaboration.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the conceptual part. If you look into the formula for std/rms, it should help.

Comment: Thanks for you good explanation!

(2) is clear

on (1) still one point is not clear for me to understand the essence. You mentioned "calculates the standard deviation of the boolean array". So the booleans values are converted into 1 and 0 (false) intrinsically?.

Comment: @ArunGanesan Yes, that is correct. That is how Python interprets booleans as numerical values by default.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, std_acc may be calculated as the uncertainty of the accuracy score (mean_acc) for each k value in the k Nearest Neighbors classification algorithm. It looks similar to the standard error of the mean, where the uncertainty of the population mean, given a data set of several values sampled from that population, can be calculated approximately as the standard deviation of the sample divided by the number of data points (values) in the sample. This comes from the Central Limit Theorem and applies when the number of data points is large.

I have seen std_acc plotted as error bars (margins) for the plot of accuracy score (mean_acc) versus k value.

It does seem rather strange and unintuitive to use this as an uncertainty, though. The standard deviation of a boolean array (interpreted as 0's and 1's) indicates how many values are equal to the mean and equal to each other. When all predictions are correct or all are incorrect, the std of the boolean array (here np.std(y_test == y_test_predict)) is ~0. When half of the predictions are correct and half are incorrect, it is 0.5. When 25% or 75% of predictions are correct, it is ~0.43. So np.std(y_test == y_test_predict) is between 0 and 0.5. It's not clear at all that this quantifies uncertainty in the typical way of spread of values around the mean...